# How do I get Erlang's edoc:application(myproject). to work?

Tags: erlang, edoc

I'm battling to figure out Erlang's automatic documentation system. The documentation advises the use of its edoc module's application function documented at http://erlang.org/doc/man/edoc.html#application-2

I've set up my subdirectories as so:

```
myproject/
├── src/
├── ebin/
│   └── myproject.app
├── include/
├── priv/
└── doc/
    └── overview.edoc
```

I can't figure out from the documentation if the application referred to in the edoc function *application* has anything to do with the myproject.app file, but it doesn't seem to.

The error I get is:

```
1> edoc:application(myproject).
edoc: cannot find application directory for 'myproject'.
** exception exit: error
     in function  edoc:application/2 (edoc.erl, line 165)
```

Any suggestions of what the magic incantation to get this to work gratefully received.

Comment: If your Erlang code path (http://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html) is not set up to point to the ebin directory of your application (".../myproject/ebin"), EDoc and other tools will not be able to locate the application by name. See http://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#lib_dir-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> application(Application::atom(), Options::proplist()) -> ok
>
> Run EDoc on an application in its default app-directory.

I don't know where it is :o)

You can use the command  `edoc:application(myproject,".",[]).` at myproject level, it will create a doc directory in the src one.

> application(Application::atom(), Dir::filename(), Options::proplist())
>   -> ok
>
> Run EDoc on an application located in the specified directory.

I prefer to create and manage application with [rebar3](https://www.rebar3.org/) which does a lot of work for you with a simple configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

To get the documentation put in the ./myproject/doc subdirectory, rather than the default ./myproject/ebin/doc directory, I used the following run from the project root directory ./myproject/

```
edoc:application(myproject, ".", [{dir, "doc"}, {subpackages, true}]).
```

Something that tripped me up was files referred to in overview.edoc need to be relative to the ./doc subdirectory (which makes sense in retrospect) as in:

> @headerfile "../include/global.hrl"